# How start service repeat with alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-intent

I want create a service run background (too when app don't work) with alarmmanger.
Can you help me this problem?

Comment: Have to already searched for solutions, tutorials, etc? There's plenty of examples already described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

alarmManager.setRepeating(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000*10,
    pendingIntent);//10s
```